# PHP cURL XML files Slow Response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to return XML from other website using cURL , but why the process is so slow ? Here's my code so far :

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = 'http://www.simbrief.com/ofp/flightplans/xml/1497850469_B5D3D239A1.xml';
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);     
if(curl_errno($ch)) return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$data = file_get_contents_curl($url);       
echo $data;
```

The value return empty response (since I add timeout option to 10s , so I assume the data didn't fully transferred) and what it makes more strange is this script works on my local server (using XAMPP) , but it doesn't work on my hosting.

Any kind of helps will be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Sounds likes a network issue independent to curl. Analyze the network traffic, contact the support personnel of your hosting, they should be able to tell you, I can not, sorry. For getting more information about the underlying network operations, see my previous [answer of "Php - Debugging Curl"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i think you were right, it was the hosting issue , i'm trying to contact them right now , and see what would be the best solution